# Append the value of an input to a matching "name" tag div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags

**Goal:** Append the value added to an input to the div with the matching `name="" tag value`.

**Problem:** The code I proved (below) works fine when there is only one div and one input or even two divs and one input but when I add a second input the code doesn't perform as it did when there was only one input.

```js
$('.example-default-value').each(function() {
  var default_value = this.value;
  $(this).focus(function() {
    if (this.value == default_value) {
      this.value = '';
    }
  });
  $(this).blur(function() {
    if (this.value == '') {
      this.value = default_value;
    }
  });
});

function example_append() {

  if ($('.example-textarea').attr('name') === $('.example').attr('name')) {
    $('.example').append($('.example-textarea').val());
  }

};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example" name="add" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);float: left; margin: 5px 0pt; padding: 5px;">Example div</div>

<div class="example" name="add1" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);float: left; margin: 5px 0pt; padding: 5px;">Example div</div>

<form>
  <div><textarea class="example-default-value example-textarea" name="add1" style="width: 400px; height: 50px;">Type some text in here to be appended</textarea></div>

  <div><textarea class="example-default-value example-textarea" name="add" style="width: 400px; height: 50px;">Type some text in here to be appended</textarea></div>

  <div><input type="button" value="Append" onclick="example_append()" /></div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should target the desired elements using [Attribute value Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) and the get its value.

```
function example_append() {
  $('.example').append(function() {
    return $('.example-textarea[name=' + $(this).attr('name') + ']').val()
  });
}
```

```js
function example_append() {
  $('.example').append(function() {
    return $('.example-textarea[name=' + $(this).attr('name') + ']').val()
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example" name="add" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);float: left; margin: 5px 0pt; padding: 5px;">Example div</div>

<div class="example" name="add1" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);float: left; margin: 5px 0pt; padding: 5px;">Example div</div>

<form>
  <div><textarea class="example-default-value example-textarea" name="add1" style="width: 400px; height: 50px;">Type some text in here to be appended</textarea></div>

  <div><textarea class="example-default-value example-textarea" name="add" style="width: 400px; height: 50px;">Type some text in here to be appended</textarea></div>

  <div><input type="button" value="Append" onclick="example_append()" /></div>

</form>
```

Comment: so I don't even need the first part of the JQuery?

Comment: @johnsmith, I have only modified the relevant code. You are the better judge for _first part_

Answer (score 0):

There are more than one `textareas`, so you need to apply loop.

```js
function example_append() {
  const divs = $('div');
  const inputs = $('.example-textarea');

  inputs.each(function() {
    const that = $(this);
    divs.each(function(i, div) {
      if ($(div).attr('name') == that.attr('name')) {
        $(div).text(that.val());
      }
    });

  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example" name="add" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);float: left; margin: 5px 0pt; padding: 5px;">Example div</div>
<div class="example" name="add1" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);float: left; margin: 5px 0pt; padding: 5px;">Example div</div>
<form>
  <div><textarea class="example-default-value example-textarea" name="add1" style="width: 400px; height: 50px;">Type some text in here to be appended</textarea></div>
  <div><textarea class="example-default-value example-textarea" name="add" style="width: 400px; height: 50px;">Type some text in here to be appended</textarea></div>
  <div><input type="button" value="Append" onclick="example_append()" /></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `textareas` don't have unique names, so this code won't work (multiple elements are found):

```
if ($('.example-textarea').attr('name') === $('.example').attr('name')){
    $('.example').append($('.example-textarea').val());
}
```

Here is a vanilla JS (i.e. no JQuery) example you can use to get the desired results:

```html
<div id="add1"></div>
<div id="add"></div>

<textarea name="add1"></textarea>
<textarea name="add"></textarea>

<button>append</button>
```

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('textarea')
  .forEach(t => {
    let name = t.getAttribute('name');
    let value = t.value;
    document.getElementById(name).innerHTML = value;
  });
});
```